# Base Url returns as IP address Lumen 5.7

Tags: reactjs, apache, nginx, lumen

I'm having a problem with links returning the base url as the host machine's ip address in Lumen of the `.env` setting as follows:

**.env excerpt:**

```
APP_URL=http://example.com
```

However, request get by Lumen on the live server returns the link as http://192.168.16.18.

I am using React js in front side and Lumen in backend side how I will get domain name?

In `$request` Lumen side I am not getting domain name it's working in local but server it's return IP address.

The internal server (192.168.16.18) runs nginx.

```
$domain = parse_url(request()->root())['host']; 
echo $domain;
```

$domain print '192.168.16.18' i need 'example.com'

Comment: `request get by Lumen` - what does this mean? Show us the code that returns the IP.

Comment: Lumen is a API framwork of laravel, when i send request from front side it's show
 http://example.com/home but when i print $reques in lumen  in this it's show base  url http://192.168.16.18/home

Comment: AFAIK the `request()` comes from the web server, and the host name it shows is not related to your `APP_URL`.  If your web server is not configured with a host name, `request()` won't show one.  In other words, you need to set up a `server_name` in your nginx config.